# PL/SQL: Creating a Trigger on one table to update the item quantity contained within a separate table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a trigger that updates the in stock quantity of a tool when the tool is returned, and also print a message stating the tool's new quantity in stock. I have two tables: Tool (stores tool info, including in stock quantity) and Rental (stores rental transaction information, including the date/time it was returned).

The returned_time column remains NULL until the tool is returned. I've created a trigger that fires when the return_time is updated to a value other than NULL. Below is my code for creating the trigger:

```
create or replace trigger update_quantity_trigger 
    after update of return_time on rental
    for each row when (old.return_time is null and new.return_time is not null)

declare
    t_name tool.tname%type; --tool name variable
    t_quantity tool.quantity%type; --tool quantity variable

begin
    update tool set quantity = quantity + 1
        where tid = :new.tid;

    select tname into t_name
        from tool t
        where tid = :new.tid;

    select quantity into t_quantity
        from tool t
        where tid = :new.tid;

    dbms_output.put_line('The quantity of ' || t_name || 's is now ' || t_quantity);
end;
```

I'm just tested with this simple update statement

```
update rental set return_time = systimestamp
    where rid = 5;
```

After running the code to create the trigger, I receive the message "TRIGGER_UPDATE_QUANTITY compiled" without any errors; however, after executing the update statement, I get the following error:

"SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'TOOL_QUANTITY_UPDATE_TRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger."

If I drop the trigger, the update statement works as expected. Any ideas what's causing this error? I assume it's an issue with my statements in the body of my trigger; however, I cannot seem to rectify it.

For reference, here are the tables created along with some sample records

```
create table tool
(tid int, --- tool id 
tname varchar(50), -- tool name 
ctid int, --- category id 
quantity int, 
primary key (tid),
foreign key (ctid) references category
);

insert into tool values(1,'21 inch electric mower',2,2);
insert into tool values(2,'30 inch large gasoline mower',3,2);

insert into tool values(3,'small carpet cleaner',4,2);
insert into tool values(4,'large carpet cleaner',4,2);

create table rental 
(
rid int, --- rental id 
cid int, --- customer id 
tid int, --- tool id
tuid int, --- time unit id
num_unit int, --- number of units, if unit = 1 hour, num_unit = 5 means 5 hours. 
start_time timestamp, -- rental start time 
end_time timestamp, --- suppose rental end_time 
return_time timestamp,--- actual return time 
credit_card varchar(20),
total number, --- total charge 
primary key (rid),
foreign key(cid) references cust,
foreign key(tid) references tool,
foreign key(tuid) references time_unit
);

insert into rental values(1,1,1,1,4,timestamp '2019-08-01 
10:00:00.00',null,null,'123456789',null);

insert into rental values(2,2,3,2,1,timestamp '2019-08-11 
10:00:00.00',null,null,'123456789',null);

insert into rental values(3,2,1,1,5,timestamp '2019-08-12 
21:00:00.00',null,null,'123456789',null);

insert into rental values(4,3,3,1,4,timestamp '2019-08-13 
19:00:00.00',null,null,'12222828828',null);

insert into rental values(5,3,3,1,4,timestamp '2019-08-13 
19:00:00.00',null,null,'12222828828',null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the error is on this trigger, and not an earlier version. Your error message references trigger TOOL_QUANTITY_UPDATE_TRIGGER but the posted trigger is "update_quantity_trigger". Those are not the same object. BTW you can reduce the trigger to a single SQL statement by using the return clause on the update:

```
create or replace trigger update_quantity_trigger
       after update of return_time on rental
       for each row when (old.return_time is null and new.return_time is not null)
   declare
       t_name tool.tname%type; --tool name variable
       t_quantity tool.quantity%type; --tool quantity variable
   begin
       update tool set quantity = quantity + 1
            where tid = :new.tid 
        returning tname, quantity
             into t_name, t_quantity;

       dbms_output.put_line('The quantity of ' || t_name || 's is now ' || t_quantity);
   end;
```

Comment: This was exactly what was causing the error! I dropped all of my existing triggers and re-ran all of the code and it executed as expected. I'm relatively new to pl/sql and I'm having a difficult time remembering that objects still exist in the db even if I have deleted the code.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for sample data. I created tables (by removing foreign key constraints as I don't have those tables):

```
SQL> create table tool
  2  (tid int, --- tool id
  3  tname varchar(50), -- tool name
  4  ctid int, --- category id
  5  quantity int,
  6  primary key (tid)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into tool values(1,'21 inch electric mower',2,2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tool values(2,'30 inch large gasoline mower',3,2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tool values(3,'small carpet cleaner',4,2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tool values(4,'large carpet cleaner',4,2);

1 row created.

SQL> create table rental
  2  (
  3  rid int, --- rental id
  4  cid int, --- customer id
  5  tid int, --- tool id
  6  tuid int, --- time unit id
  7  num_unit int, --- number of units, if unit = 1 hour, num_unit = 5 means 5 hours.
  8  start_time timestamp, -- rental start time
  9  end_time timestamp, --- suppose rental end_time
 10  return_time timestamp,--- actual return time
 11  credit_card varchar(20),
 12  total number, --- total charge
 13  primary key (rid)
 14  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into rental values(1,1,1,1,4,timestamp '2019-08-01 10:00:00.00',null,null,'123456789',null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into rental values(2,2,3,2,1,timestamp '2019-08-11 10:00:00.00',null,null,'123456789',null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into rental values(3,2,1,1,5,timestamp '2019-08-12 21:00:00.00',null,null,'123456789',null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into rental values(4,3,3,1,4,timestamp '2019-08-13 19:00:00.00',null,null,'12222828828',null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into rental values(5,3,3,1,4,timestamp '2019-08-13 19:00:00.00',null,null,'12222828828',null);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger update_quantity_trigger
  2      after update of return_time on rental
  3      for each row when (old.return_time is null and new.return_time is not null)
  4  declare
  5      t_name tool.tname%type; --tool name variable
  6      t_quantity tool.quantity%type; --tool quantity variable
  7  begin
  8      update tool set quantity = quantity + 1
  9          where tid = :new.tid;
 10
 11      select tname into t_name
 12          from tool t
 13          where tid = :new.tid;
 14
 15      select quantity into t_quantity
 16          from tool t
 17          where tid = :new.tid;
 18      dbms_output.put_line('The quantity of ' || t_name || 's is now ' || t_quantity);
 19  end;
 20  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select rid, cid, return_time from rental;

       RID        CID RETURN_TIME
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
         1          1
         2          2
         3          2
         4          3
         5          3

SQL> update rental set return_time = systimestamp where rid = 5;
The quantity of small carpet cleaners is now 3

1 row updated.

SQL> select rid, cid, return_time from rental;

       RID        CID RETURN_TIME
---------- ---------- ------------------------------
         1          1
         2          2
         3          2
         4          3
         5          3 21.11.19 08:53:46,073000

SQL>
```

In other words, it *works* on my 11g XE.

Comment: Thank you for breaking down/showing me the expected results that you returned from the program. I'm using SQL Developer as my IDE. Could my problem be related to the this?

Comment: You're welcome. SQL Developer isn't the issue here. I ran that in SQL Developer first, then switched to SQL*Plus to copy/paste the result. There must be something else. If possible, do as I did - copy/paste YOUR session.